# Php mail strange behaviour \r\n and html content

Tags: php, email, header, html-email

I'm building a simple cms system, with mail sent.
After one week without any problems next source start FAILed-

```
$headers .= "Importance: High\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";

``IF (mail ($email, $subject, $message, $headers, " -f". $email) === TRUE)``
```

HTML mail content was ok.

So, after long time I discovered fail was in \r\n, between

```
MIME-Version: 1.0\r\ncontent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1... - FAIL
```

When I put space after \r\n -

```
MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1... - TRUE
```

But mail html content is in plain text.

So I  changed the first letter of - content to ANSII character - &-#-67;ontent... and it works,

But again with html in plain text.

Maybe ANSII char doing that wrong displayng of html ?

Also \r\n between -
`...content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit...` is TRUE !

I had to change previous mail verification to  -

```
IF(mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers))
```

I have never seen nothing like that and I don't understand the problem here, I think the problem is in hosting server.

Please, help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If at all possible, don't build your own HTML mailer.  Use a well-tested class like Swiftmailer or similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brad, Jake.
Im solved that with phpmailer.

Also, mystery of ***\r\n***  behaviour on that line and there, is still unsolved...